# Debug APC in centos 5

Tags: php, apc

pecl install apc

### pecl/apc is already installed and is the same as the released version 3.1.13

install failed

### this show that i already install apc, but the apc cannot work

```
/usr/local/lib/php.ini
/usr/local/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
/etc/php.ini
extension=apc.so
```

### i add last line of code in all php.ini

but i check my **phpinfo**
my apc is not in the list

when i run the function
this is what i get Call to undefined function apc_fetch()

how can i debug this issue
btw i even restart my server.

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/apc.so' - ./usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/apc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0,

Comment: So is there a file in that exact path?

Comment: ya i put it in exact path, i solve it by remove extension_dir ./, xdebug is ok with the extension_dir, but not with apc